# Capturing Drupal auto-complete values/events and altering form components on found results

Tags: javascript, json, drupal, autocomplete, dom-events

I'm not an expert on AJAX, Drupal or Javascript, but I'll do my best to make my question as clear as possible.

I am running drupal 7 on MySQL in a dev environment. I wrote my own module 'acid' for handling custom autocomplete functions

I'm building a site for a company to allow them to add customer satisfaction forms for all of their sites. In my db, i have a table of 'acid_company' and 'acid_sites', with the structure being that one company can have multiple sites.

When a user wants to add a site, he first has to enter the company name, to see if the name of the company already exists in the DB. I have got the autocomplete function for the company name field working properly, but what I want to do is disable (or change) the submit button of the 'add company' form to instead take the user to the form where he can add a site to a company.

So the steps would be:

- [user clicks 'add site'] -> [present 'add company' form] -> [process user input on company_name autocomplete field]->
- company allready exists -> [change form submit button to 'add site' (or present a link to 'add site form')]
- company does not exist -> leave submit button unchanged -> user presses submit [add company and take user to 'add site' form] *(I have this working already!)*

So what I would like to know, is how do I capture the event from the company_name element  when a user has selected a company name from the found results and change the other form components accordingly.

Something like:

```
(user inputs company name) -> results found -> (user clicks one of the found results)<br />
<code>
do_disableForm()<br />
{<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;this.form.addcompany.company_name.disable();<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;this.form.addcompany.submit.disable();<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;this.a.addsite.setVisable(TRUE);
}<br />
</code>
```

The "<a href='?q=addsite&companyid=xx'>add site</a>" link would also need to have the company ID in its hyperlink reference, so I would also need to capture this from the results. Maybe in a hidden form component.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*As a sidenote, I have tried to follow 'the drupal way' as much as possible :)*

Answer (score 6):

In `misc/autocomplete.js` it is declared the JavaScript object **Drupal.jsAc** used for autocomplete. This is probably what you are looking for:

```
/**
 * Puts the currently highlighted suggestion into the autocomplete field.
 */
Drupal.jsAC.prototype.select = function (node) {
  this.input.value = $(node).data('autocompleteValue');
};
```

In general, in JavaScript, almost everything can be overriden, including prototypes.

So you just have to copy it in your own custom .js file, and add your custom code `do_disableForm`